# Detecting registered & running service without administrator rights

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-services

I have a desktop application should behave differently depending on if an optional service is running. I was using the service control manager to check if the service was registered, and if so, whether or not it was running. This worked well until I realized that this seems to require the desktop application to run as administrator.

What would be the best way of checking these conditions (registered and running) in my desktop application, without requiring administrative rights?

Comment: Use IPC to communicate with the service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need admin rights to query the SCM for service information.

Call [`OpenSCManager()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684323.aspx) requesting `SC_MANAGER_CONNECT` access, then call [`OpenService()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330.aspx) requesting `SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS` access.  That will tell you if the service is installed or not. If so, then call [`QueryServiceStatus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684939.aspx) to find out if it is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm more familiar with the C# side, I'm not sure if there's a formal API for doing this in C++ that doesn't require some form of elevated privileges.  That said, a couple of alternatives come to mind.

1. You could have your service open a server socket and listen on the localhost address (127.0.0.1) on a specific port.  When your application starts running, it would connect to this address.  If the connection succeeded, your service is running.
2. Another option would be to have your service create a named, system-level mutex when it starts running and close it when the service closes.  Your application could check to see if the mutex exists.  If it does, your service is running.

HTH

Comment: A system mutex is a good idea, I didn't think of that. My service actually already contains a socket, however, there is a slight delay between the service starting and the socket listening. That is why the desktop client needs to know if the service exists (so that it knows if it may have to perform multiple connection attempts).

Comment: If you use a mutex, make sure you put it in the `Global` namespace and give it a NULL DACL so everyone can access it (unless you want to manually construct an ACL/DACL that fine-tunes who can access it). In other words, don't set the `lpMutexAttributes` parameter of `CreateMutex()` to NULL, give it a real `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` struct to specify the mutex's security.